# ¿Como reiniciar un valor de un picker, framework7?

Tags: jquery, framework7

Buen dia, actualmente creo de la siguiente forma un picker:

```
myApp.picker({
        input: '#departamento_alterna',
        rotateEffect: false,
        onClose: function (picker) {
            console.log(picker.value)
            Cod_depto_alterna = picker.value[0];
            $$("#municipio_alterna").val("");
            $$("#seccion_alterna").val("");
            if (pais == 8) {
                if (!Cod_depto_alterna) Cod_depto_alterna = departamentos_codigos[0]
                cargarMunicipios(pais, Cod_depto_alterna)
            }
        },
        formatValue: function (p, values, displayValues) {
            return displayValues[0];
        },
        cols: [{
            values: departamentos_codigos,
            displayValues: departamentos_texto,
            textAlign: 'left'
        }]
    });
```

El cual me devuelve un listado de departamentos, pero debo realizar la siguiente validacion:
cuando un boton este checked debe habilitarse el campo, pero al quitar checked este picker debe reiniciarse asi como que nunca se haya seleccionado, ya que al momento de seleccionar un valor este ya no se puede deseleccionar.

intente con `$('#departamento_alterna').val("");` pero eso no lo reinicia.

Gracias.